# Postfix config, prevent server from blind relay

Tags: postfix, mac-osx-server

All,

I'm having a bit of a weird issue. I have a legacy Postfix smtp server that just yesterday started acting as a relay for spam. From what I can tell, the issue is that whatever spam bot is doing it, figured out that they could send email using fakeusername@mydomain.edu to send through my server to anywhere. I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to prevent this.

The mail server, at this point, only exists to either accept mail for a few internal aliases, our hosted mailman lists (also aliases), and act as an SMTP server for a couple users that still have it set as their primary SMTP server.

So, really, I should be able to tell the server "only accept SASL auth'd clients, OR only accept mail destined for local accounts", yes?

Other info, running Mac OS X Server 10.6.8, Postfix 2.5.14. Dovecot is disabled.

Here's my postconf, scrubbed slightly. I don't get what's missing here... but I'm guessing it's something obvious...

```
2bounce_notice_recipient = postmaster
access_map_reject_code = 554
address_verify_default_transport = $default_transport
address_verify_local_transport = $local_transport
address_verify_map = 
address_verify_negative_cache = yes
address_verify_negative_expire_time = 3d
address_verify_negative_refresh_time = 3h
address_verify_poll_count = 3
address_verify_poll_delay = 3s
address_verify_positive_expire_time = 31d
address_verify_positive_refresh_time = 7d
address_verify_relay_transport = $relay_transport
address_verify_relayhost = $relayhost
address_verify_sender = $double_bounce_sender
address_verify_sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = $sender_dependent_relayhost_maps
address_verify_service_name = verify
address_verify_transport_maps = $transport_maps
address_verify_virtual_transport = $virtual_transport
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases,hash:/var/mailman/data/aliases
allow_mail_to_commands = alias, forward
allow_mail_to_files = alias, forward
allow_min_user = no
allow_percent_hack = yes
allow_untrusted_routing = no
alternate_config_directories = 
always_bcc = 
anvil_rate_time_unit = 60s
anvil_status_update_time = 600s
append_at_myorigin = yes
append_dot_mydomain = yes
application_event_drain_time = 100s
authorized_flush_users = static:anyone
authorized_mailq_users = static:anyone
authorized_submit_users = static:anyone
backwards_bounce_logfile_compatibility = yes
berkeley_db_create_buffer_size = 16777216
berkeley_db_read_buffer_size = 131072
best_mx_transport = 
biff = no
body_checks = 
body_checks_size_limit = 51200
bounce_notice_recipient = postmaster
bounce_queue_lifetime = 5d
bounce_service_name = bounce
bounce_size_limit = 50000
bounce_template_file = 
broken_sasl_auth_clients = no
canonical_classes = envelope_sender, envelope_recipient, header_sender, header_recipient
canonical_maps = 
check_for_od_forward = yes
cleanup_service_name = cleanup
command_directory = /usr/sbin
command_execution_directory = 
command_expansion_filter = 1234567890!@%-_=+:,./abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
command_time_limit = 1000s
config_directory = /etc/postfix
connection_cache_protocol_timeout = 5s
connection_cache_service_name = scache
connection_cache_status_update_time = 600s
connection_cache_ttl_limit = 2s
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
cyrus_sasl_config_path = 
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
daemon_timeout = 18000s
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debug_peer_list = 
default_database_type = hash
default_delivery_slot_cost = 5
default_delivery_slot_discount = 50
default_delivery_slot_loan = 3
default_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = 1
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 20
default_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback = 1
default_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback = 1
default_destination_rate_delay = 0s
default_destination_recipient_limit = 50
default_extra_recipient_limit = 1000
default_minimum_delivery_slots = 3
default_privs = nobody
default_process_limit = 100
default_rbl_reply = $rbl_code Service unavailable; $rbl_class [$rbl_what] blocked using $rbl_domain${rbl_reason?; $rbl_reason}
default_recipient_limit = 20000
default_recipient_refill_delay = 5s
default_recipient_refill_limit = 100
default_transport = smtp
default_verp_delimiters = +=
defer_code = 450
defer_service_name = defer
defer_transports = 
delay_logging_resolution_limit = 2
delay_notice_recipient = postmaster
delay_warning_time = 0h
deliver_lock_attempts = 20
deliver_lock_delay = 1s
destination_concurrency_feedback_debug = no
detect_8bit_encoding_header = yes
disable_dns_lookups = no
disable_mime_input_processing = no
disable_mime_output_conversion = no
disable_verp_bounces = no
disable_vrfy_command = yes
dont_remove = 0
double_bounce_sender = double-bounce
duplicate_filter_limit = 1000
empty_address_recipient = MAILER-DAEMON
empty_address_relayhost_maps_lookup_key = <>
enable_original_recipient = yes
enable_server_options = yes
error_notice_recipient = postmaster
error_service_name = error
execution_directory_expansion_filter = 1234567890!@%-_=+:,./abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
expand_owner_alias = no
export_environment = TZ MAIL_CONFIG LANG
fallback_transport = 
fallback_transport_maps = 
fast_flush_domains = $relay_domains
fast_flush_purge_time = 7d
fast_flush_refresh_time = 12h
fault_injection_code = 0
flush_service_name = flush
fork_attempts = 5
fork_delay = 1s
forward_expansion_filter = 1234567890!@%-_=+:,./abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
forward_path = $home/.forward${recipient_delimiter}${extension}, $home/.forward
frozen_delivered_to = yes
hash_queue_depth = 1
hash_queue_names = deferred, defer
header_address_token_limit = 10240
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/custom_header_checks
header_size_limit = 102400
helpful_warnings = yes
home_mailbox = 
hopcount_limit = 50
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
ignore_mx_lookup_error = no
import_environment = MAIL_CONFIG MAIL_DEBUG MAIL_LOGTAG TZ XAUTHORITY DISPLAY LANG=C
in_flow_delay = 1s
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
initial_destination_concurrency = 5
internal_mail_filter_classes = 
invalid_hostname_reject_code = 554
ipc_idle = 5s
ipc_timeout = 3600s
ipc_ttl = 1000s
line_length_limit = 2048
lmtp_bind_address = 
lmtp_bind_address6 = 
lmtp_body_checks = 
lmtp_cname_overrides_servername = no
lmtp_connect_timeout = 0s
lmtp_connection_cache_destinations = 
lmtp_connection_cache_on_demand = yes
lmtp_connection_cache_time_limit = 2s
lmtp_connection_reuse_time_limit = 300s
lmtp_data_done_timeout = 600s
lmtp_data_init_timeout = 120s
lmtp_data_xfer_timeout = 180s
lmtp_defer_if_no_mx_address_found = no
lmtp_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit
lmtp_destination_concurrency_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_limit
lmtp_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback
lmtp_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback
lmtp_destination_rate_delay = $default_destination_rate_delay
lmtp_destination_recipient_limit = $default_destination_recipient_limit
lmtp_discard_lhlo_keyword_address_maps = 
lmtp_discard_lhlo_keywords = 
lmtp_enforce_tls = no
lmtp_generic_maps = 
lmtp_header_checks = 
lmtp_host_lookup = dns
lmtp_initial_destination_concurrency = $initial_destination_concurrency
lmtp_lhlo_name = $myhostname
lmtp_lhlo_timeout = 300s
lmtp_line_length_limit = 990
lmtp_mail_timeout = 300s
lmtp_mime_header_checks = 
lmtp_mx_address_limit = 5
lmtp_mx_session_limit = 2
lmtp_nested_header_checks = 
lmtp_pix_workaround_delay_time = 10s
lmtp_pix_workaround_maps = 
lmtp_pix_workaround_threshold_time = 500s
lmtp_pix_workarounds = disable_esmtp,delay_dotcrlf
lmtp_quit_timeout = 300s
lmtp_quote_rfc821_envelope = yes
lmtp_randomize_addresses = yes
lmtp_rcpt_timeout = 300s
lmtp_rset_timeout = 20s
lmtp_sasl_auth_cache_name = 
lmtp_sasl_auth_cache_time = 90d
lmtp_sasl_auth_enable = no
lmtp_sasl_auth_soft_bounce = yes
lmtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = 
lmtp_sasl_password_maps = 
lmtp_sasl_path = 
lmtp_sasl_security_options = noplaintext, noanonymous
lmtp_sasl_tls_security_options = $lmtp_sasl_security_options
lmtp_sasl_tls_verified_security_options = $lmtp_sasl_tls_security_options
lmtp_sasl_type = cyrus
lmtp_send_xforward_command = no
lmtp_sender_dependent_authentication = no
lmtp_skip_5xx_greeting = yes
lmtp_starttls_timeout = 300s
lmtp_tcp_port = 24
lmtp_tls_CAfile = 
lmtp_tls_CApath = 
lmtp_tls_cert_file = 
lmtp_tls_dcert_file = 
lmtp_tls_dkey_file = $lmtp_tls_dcert_file
lmtp_tls_enforce_peername = yes
lmtp_tls_exclude_ciphers = 
lmtp_tls_fingerprint_cert_match = 
lmtp_tls_fingerprint_digest = md5
lmtp_tls_key_file = $lmtp_tls_cert_file
lmtp_tls_loglevel = 0
lmtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
lmtp_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = 
lmtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
lmtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = no
lmtp_tls_per_site = 
lmtp_tls_policy_maps = 
lmtp_tls_scert_verifydepth = 9
lmtp_tls_secure_cert_match = nexthop
lmtp_tls_security_level = 
lmtp_tls_session_cache_database = 
lmtp_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
lmtp_tls_verify_cert_match = hostname
lmtp_use_tls = no
lmtp_xforward_timeout = 300s
local_command_shell = 
local_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit
local_destination_concurrency_limit = 2
local_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback
local_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback
local_destination_rate_delay = $default_destination_rate_delay
local_destination_recipient_limit = 1
local_header_rewrite_clients = permit_inet_interfaces
local_initial_destination_concurrency = $initial_destination_concurrency
local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
local_transport = local:$myhostname
luser_relay = 
mail_name = Postfix
mail_owner = _postfix
mail_release_date = 20110707
mail_spool_directory = /var/mail
mail_version = 2.5.14
mailbox_command = 
mailbox_command_maps = 
mailbox_delivery_lock = flock, dotlock
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailbox_transport = dovecot
mailbox_transport_maps = 
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
maps_rbl_domains = 
maps_rbl_reject_code = 554
masquerade_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender, header_recipient
masquerade_domains = 
masquerade_exceptions = 
max_idle = 100s
max_use = 100
maximal_backoff_time = 4000s
maximal_queue_lifetime = 5d
message_reject_characters = 
message_size_limit = 31457280
message_strip_characters = 
milter_command_timeout = 30s
milter_connect_macros = j {daemon_name} v
milter_connect_timeout = 30s
milter_content_timeout = 300s
milter_data_macros = i
milter_default_action = tempfail
milter_end_of_data_macros = i
milter_end_of_header_macros = i
milter_helo_macros = {tls_version} {cipher} {cipher_bits} {cert_subject} {cert_issuer}
milter_macro_daemon_name = $myhostname
milter_macro_v = $mail_name $mail_version
milter_mail_macros = i {auth_type} {auth_authen} {auth_author} {mail_addr}
milter_protocol = 2
milter_rcpt_macros = i {rcpt_addr}
milter_unknown_command_macros = 
mime_boundary_length_limit = 2048
mime_header_checks = $header_checks
mime_nesting_limit = 100
minimal_backoff_time = 300s
multi_recipient_bounce_reject_code = 554
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain
mydomain = domain.com
mydomain_fallback = localhost
myhostname = server.domain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8,123.123.0.0/16
mynetworks_style = subnet
myorigin = $myhostname
nested_header_checks = $header_checks
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
non_fqdn_reject_code = 554
non_smtpd_milters = 
notify_classes = resource, software
owner_request_special = no
parent_domain_matches_subdomains = debug_peer_list,fast_flush_domains,mynetworks,permit_mx_backup_networks,qmqpd_authorized_clients,relay_domains,smtpd_access_maps
permit_mx_backup_networks = 
pickup_service_name = pickup
plaintext_reject_code = 450
prepend_delivered_header = command, file, forward
process_id_directory = pid
propagate_unmatched_extensions = canonical, virtual
proxy_interfaces = 
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $sender_bcc_maps $recipient_bcc_maps $smtp_generic_maps $lmtp_generic_maps
proxy_write_maps = $smtp_sasl_auth_cache_name $lmtp_sasl_auth_cache_name
qmgr_clog_warn_time = 300s
qmgr_fudge_factor = 100
qmgr_message_active_limit = 20000
qmgr_message_recipient_limit = 20000
qmgr_message_recipient_minimum = 10
qmqpd_authorized_clients = 
qmqpd_client_port_logging = no
qmqpd_error_delay = 1s
qmqpd_timeout = 300s
queue_directory = /private/var/spool/postfix
queue_file_attribute_count_limit = 100
queue_minfree = 0
queue_run_delay = 300s
queue_service_name = qmgr
rbl_reply_maps = 
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
receive_override_options = 
recipient_bcc_maps = 
recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient, header_recipient
recipient_canonical_maps = 
recipient_delimiter = +
reject_code = 554
relay_clientcerts = 
relay_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit
relay_destination_concurrency_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_limit
relay_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback
relay_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback
relay_destination_rate_delay = $default_destination_rate_delay
relay_destination_recipient_limit = $default_destination_recipient_limit
relay_domains = $mydestination
relay_domains_reject_code = 554
relay_initial_destination_concurrency = $initial_destination_concurrency
relay_recipient_maps = 
relay_transport = relay
relayhost = 
relocated_maps = 
remote_header_rewrite_domain = 
require_home_directory = no
resolve_dequoted_address = yes
resolve_null_domain = no
resolve_numeric_domain = no
rewrite_service_name = rewrite
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/examples
send_cyrus_sasl_authzid = no
sender_bcc_maps = 
sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender
sender_canonical_maps = 
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = 
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
service_throttle_time = 60s
setgid_group = _postdrop
show_user_unknown_table_name = yes
showq_service_name = showq
smtp_always_send_ehlo = yes
smtp_bind_address = 
smtp_bind_address6 = 
smtp_body_checks = 
smtp_cname_overrides_servername = no
smtp_connect_timeout = 30s
smtp_connection_cache_destinations = 
smtp_connection_cache_on_demand = yes
smtp_connection_cache_time_limit = 2s
smtp_connection_reuse_time_limit = 300s
smtp_data_done_timeout = 600s
smtp_data_init_timeout = 120s
smtp_data_xfer_timeout = 180s
smtp_defer_if_no_mx_address_found = no
smtp_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_limit
smtp_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback
smtp_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback
smtp_destination_rate_delay = $default_destination_rate_delay
smtp_destination_recipient_limit = $default_destination_recipient_limit
smtp_discard_ehlo_keyword_address_maps = 
smtp_discard_ehlo_keywords = 
smtp_enforce_tls = no
smtp_fallback_relay = $fallback_relay
smtp_generic_maps = 
smtp_header_checks = 
smtp_helo_name = $myhostname
smtp_helo_timeout = 300s
smtp_host_lookup = dns
smtp_initial_destination_concurrency = $initial_destination_concurrency
smtp_line_length_limit = 990
smtp_mail_timeout = 300s
smtp_mime_header_checks = 
smtp_mx_address_limit = 5
smtp_mx_session_limit = 2
smtp_nested_header_checks = 
smtp_never_send_ehlo = no
smtp_pix_workaround_delay_time = 10s
smtp_pix_workaround_maps = 
smtp_pix_workaround_threshold_time = 500s
smtp_pix_workarounds = disable_esmtp,delay_dotcrlf
smtp_quit_timeout = 300s
smtp_quote_rfc821_envelope = yes
smtp_randomize_addresses = yes
smtp_rcpt_timeout = 300s
smtp_rset_timeout = 20s
smtp_sasl_auth_cache_name = 
smtp_sasl_auth_cache_time = 90d
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtp_sasl_auth_soft_bounce = yes
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = 
smtp_sasl_password_maps = 
smtp_sasl_path = 
smtp_sasl_security_options = noplaintext, noanonymous
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtp_sasl_security_options
smtp_sasl_tls_verified_security_options = $smtp_sasl_tls_security_options
smtp_sasl_type = cyrus
smtp_send_xforward_command = no
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = no
smtp_skip_5xx_greeting = yes
smtp_skip_quit_response = yes
smtp_starttls_timeout = 300s
smtp_tls_CAfile = 
smtp_tls_CApath = 
smtp_tls_cert_file = 
smtp_tls_dcert_file = 
smtp_tls_dkey_file = $smtp_tls_dcert_file
smtp_tls_enforce_peername = yes
smtp_tls_exclude_ciphers = 
smtp_tls_fingerprint_cert_match = 
smtp_tls_fingerprint_digest = md5
smtp_tls_key_file = $smtp_tls_cert_file
smtp_tls_loglevel = 0
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtp_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = 
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = no
smtp_tls_per_site = 
smtp_tls_policy_maps = 
smtp_tls_scert_verifydepth = 9
smtp_tls_secure_cert_match = nexthop, dot-nexthop
smtp_tls_security_level = 
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = 
smtp_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtp_tls_verify_cert_match = hostname
smtp_use_tls = no
smtp_xforward_timeout = 300s
smtpd_authorized_verp_clients = $authorized_verp_clients
smtpd_authorized_xclient_hosts = 
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_client_connection_count_limit = 50
smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 20
smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions = ${smtpd_client_connection_limit_exceptions:$mynetworks}
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 0
smtpd_client_new_tls_session_rate_limit = 0
smtpd_client_port_logging = no
smtpd_client_recipient_rate_limit = 0
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org reject_rbl_client psbl.surriel.com reject_rbl_client multi.uribl.com reject_rbl_client dsn.rfc-ignorant.org reject_rbl_client dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org reject_rbl_client ix.dnsbl.manitu.net reject_rbl_client combined.rbl.msrbl.net reject_rbl_client rabl.nuclearelephant.com
smtpd_data_restrictions = 
smtpd_delay_open_until_valid_rcpt = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_discard_ehlo_keyword_address_maps = 
smtpd_discard_ehlo_keywords = 
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions = 
smtpd_enforce_tls = no
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 10s
smtpd_etrn_restrictions = 
smtpd_expansion_filter = \t\40!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
smtpd_forbidden_commands = CONNECT GET POST
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 5
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks reject_invalid_helo_hostname reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
smtpd_history_flush_threshold = 100
smtpd_junk_command_limit = 100
smtpd_milters = 
smtpd_noop_commands = 
smtpd_null_access_lookup_key = <>
smtpd_peername_lookup = yes
smtpd_policy_service_max_idle = 300s
smtpd_policy_service_max_ttl = 1000s
smtpd_policy_service_timeout = 100s
smtpd_proxy_ehlo = $myhostname
smtpd_proxy_filter = 
smtpd_proxy_timeout = 100s
smtpd_pw_server_security_options = cram-md5,plain,login
smtpd_recipient_limit = 3000
smtpd_recipient_overshoot_limit = 1000
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_invalid_hostname, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access, check_policy_service unix:private/policy
smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient = yes
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = no
smtpd_restriction_classes = 
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = no
smtpd_sasl_exceptions_networks = 
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $mydomain
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = $smtpd_sasl_security_options
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_sender_login_maps = 
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
smtpd_starttls_timeout = 300s
smtpd_timeout = 300s
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/certificates/CA.chain.pem
smtpd_tls_CApath = 
smtpd_tls_always_issue_session_ids = yes
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = no
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_ccert_verifydepth = 9
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/certificates/cert.cert.pem
smtpd_tls_dcert_file = 
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = 
smtpd_tls_dh512_param_file = 
smtpd_tls_dkey_file = $smtpd_tls_dcert_file
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = SSLv2, aNULL, ADH, eNULL
smtpd_tls_fingerprint_digest = md5
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/certificates/key.key.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 0
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = 
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_received_header = no
smtpd_tls_req_ccert = no
smtpd_tls_security_level = 
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = 
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_tls_wrappermode = no
smtpd_use_pw_server = yes
smtpd_use_tls = no
soft_bounce = no
stale_lock_time = 500s
stress = 
strict_7bit_headers = no
strict_8bitmime = no
strict_8bitmime_body = no
strict_mailbox_ownership = yes
strict_mime_encoding_domain = no
strict_rfc821_envelopes = no
sun_mailtool_compatibility = no
swap_bangpath = yes
syslog_facility = mail
syslog_name = postfix
tls_append_default_CA = no
tls_daemon_random_bytes = 32
tls_export_cipherlist = ALL:+RC4:@STRENGTH
tls_high_cipherlist = ALL:!EXPORT:!LOW:!MEDIUM:+RC4:@STRENGTH
tls_low_cipherlist = ALL:!EXPORT:+RC4:@STRENGTH
tls_medium_cipherlist = ALL:!EXPORT:!LOW:+RC4:@STRENGTH
tls_null_cipherlist = eNULL:!aNULL
tls_random_bytes = 32
tls_random_exchange_name = ${data_directory}/prng_exch
tls_random_prng_update_period = 3600s
tls_random_reseed_period = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
trace_service_name = trace
transport_maps = 
transport_retry_time = 60s
trigger_timeout = 10s
undisclosed_recipients_header = To: undisclosed-recipients:;
unknown_address_reject_code = 554
unknown_client_reject_code = 554
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 554
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 554
unknown_relay_recipient_reject_code = 554
unknown_virtual_alias_reject_code = 554
unknown_virtual_mailbox_reject_code = 554
unverified_recipient_reject_code = 554
unverified_sender_reject_code = 554
use_getpwnam_ext = yes
use_od_delivery_path = no
verp_delimiter_filter = -=+
virtual_alias_domains = $virtual_alias_maps
virtual_alias_expansion_limit = 1000
virtual_alias_maps = 
virtual_alias_recursion_limit = 1000
virtual_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_failed_cohort_limit
virtual_destination_concurrency_limit = $default_destination_concurrency_limit
virtual_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_negative_feedback
virtual_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback = $default_destination_concurrency_positive_feedback
virtual_destination_rate_delay = $default_destination_rate_delay
virtual_destination_recipient_limit = $default_destination_recipient_limit
virtual_gid_maps = 
virtual_initial_destination_concurrency = $initial_destination_concurrency
virtual_mailbox_base = 
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps
virtual_mailbox_limit = 51200000
virtual_mailbox_lock = fcntl, dotlock
virtual_mailbox_maps = 
virtual_minimum_uid = 100
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps =
```

Comment: That's a lot of config.  You probably wanted the output of `postconf -nf` instead.

Comment: So I believe I have the answer, and it wasn't the main.cf, it was the master.cf. 

It seems like it was the fact that the submission port was missing: 

  -o tls_preempt_cipherlist=yes

And worse, the smtp entry was missing both 

  -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=no

I'm not 100% sure this was the resolution, as I also worked on the main.cf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think this finally has it fixed.

My master.cf now has:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=no
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o tls_preempt_cipherlist=yes
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
```

And my main.cf is:

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases,hash:/var/mailman/data/aliases
biff = no
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
disable_vrfy_command = yes
enable_server_options = yes
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/custom_header_checks
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
inet_interfaces = all
invalid_hostname_reject_code = 554
mail_owner = _postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailbox_transport = dovecot
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
maps_rbl_domains = 
message_size_limit = 31457280
multi_recipient_bounce_reject_code = 554
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = uoregon.edu
mydomain_fallback = localhost
myhostname = server.domain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8,123.123.0.0/16
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
non_fqdn_reject_code = 554
owner_request_special = no
queue_directory = /private/var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains_reject_code = 554
relayhost = 
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/examples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = _postdrop
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 20
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org reject_rbl_client psbl.surriel.com reject_rbl_client multi.uribl.com reject_rbl_client dsn.rfc-ignorant.org reject_rbl_client dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org reject_rbl_client ix.dnsbl.manitu.net reject_rbl_client combined.rbl.msrbl.net reject_rbl_client rabl.nuclearelephant.com
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_enforce_tls = no
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 10s
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 5
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_invalid_helo_hostname reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
smtpd_pw_server_security_options = cram-md5,plain,login
smtpd_recipient_limit = 3000
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_invalid_hostname, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access, check_policy_service unix:private/policy
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $mydomain
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/certificates/chain.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/certificates/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/certificates/key.pem
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_use_pw_server = yes
smtpd_use_tls = no
tls_high_cipherlist = EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA256:+AES256:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!ECDSA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_address_reject_code = 554
unknown_client_reject_code = 554
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 554
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 554
unknown_relay_recipient_reject_code = 554
unknown_virtual_alias_reject_code = 554
unknown_virtual_mailbox_reject_code = 554
unverified_recipient_reject_code = 554
unverified_sender_reject_code = 554
virtual_alias_maps =
```

Comment: mark it as the answer then?

Comment: Apologies, it wouldn't let me when I first answered saying I had to wait.

Comment: Np naturally, just trying to help clean things up; thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

With that configuration your MTA is accepting mails from a wide network range:
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8,**123.123.0.0/16**
smtpd_client_restrictions = **permit_mynetworks** …

That means if any of these 65,024 hosts in the network 123.123.0.0/16 is compromised, it can send spam via your machine with no restrictions. You should only allow the host IP addresses for your explained purposes, i.e.:
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, **my.host.ip.addr/32**, **my.backupmx.ip.addr/32**

Comment: Additionally I've checked that network range and it points to [CNCGROUP IP network China169 Beijing Province Network](http://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/ip-address/123.123.0.0-123.123.255.255). If you don't make that configuration in your settings, consider your machine is p0wned …
In that case you should disable your machine from the network and set it up new.

Comment: Sorry, 123.123 is me obfuscating the actual /16 that I use. And yeah, that's intentional.